# Indendation issue in Python code

Tags: python, twitter

I am a beginner with python and have been trying to learn to create twitter bots to reply to tweets from the streaming API. The following is my code. I am getting the following error when I run it:

check ():
Indentation error: unindent does not match with any outer indentation level.
I cannot find any indentation error

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import json
import time

consumer_key = 
consumer_secret = 
access_token = 
access_secret = 

def check():
    datafile = file('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Handles', 'r')
    found = False
    for line in datafile:
        if status.user.screen_name in line:
            found = True
            break
    return found


class MyListener(StreamListener):


    def on_status(self, status):
        f=status.user.screen_name
        if check() :
            return True
        else:
            Append=open('Growth Handles.txt' , 'a' )
            Append.write(f)
            Append.close()
            Reply='@handlename' + 'Check out Tomorrowland 2014 Setlist . http://.... '
            api = tweepy.API(auth)
            api.update_status(Reply)
            time.sleep(45)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
twitter_stream.filter(track=['#musiclovers'])
```

Comment: Check for tabs vs. spaces.

Comment: The error should tell you what line. 4 spaces for an indent. Check the line before the error, it's the most likely culprit.

Comment: You should include the whole traceback, not just the last line.

Comment: If you copy pasted some of the code that is likely where the issue lies.

Comment: Not your error, but take care using \ in filenames, safer to use *raw strings*:  `r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Handles'`.

Comment: @mauve Thanks for the advice. I got rid of the indentation error and the code seems to be working . I am trying to post to users who tweet with a particular hashtag. But I also am trying to exclude users to whom I have already posted. When I tested, On the first try, I got a reply but on the second post to the same handle, the code gave me the following error: global name 'status' not defined. Can you please help with this

Comment: @saket.v, you should ask another question about that :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how your code looks like when using notepad++:
[image]

As you can see some of your lines are indented with 4 spaces and some with tabs.
You should really use IDE when you write code, or at least use [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (which is not an IDE but is good enough to understand errors like this).

I can really advise using [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). They have free edition and it works great.